# Java Foreign API: how to pass pointers and pointers address?

Tags: java, project-panama

I am working with the new **Java Foreign API** and I have to call two C functions (Java bindings generated using the [JExtract](https://github.com/openjdk/jextract) tool) that take in input a double pointer and a pointer:

- https://yara.readthedocs.io/en/stable/capi.html#c.yr_compiler_create
- https://yara.readthedocs.io/en/stable/capi.html#c.yr_compiler_destroy

---

```
int yr_compiler_create(YR_COMPILER** compiler)

void yr_compiler_destroy(YR_COMPILER* compiler)
```

---

In the [official YARA C API tests](https://github.com/VirusTotal/yara/blob/1b2989eee3e8c3ecb223640b7694a722bc5808ef/tests/test-api.c#L101) these methods are called as follows:

```
#include <yara.h>

voit test_compiler(){
    YR_COMPILER* compiler = NULL;
    yr_initialize();

    yr_compiler_create(&compiler);
    yr_compiler_destroy(compiler);

    yr_finalize();
}
```

---

The corresponding Java bindings are as follows:

```
/**
 * {@snippet :
 * int yr_compiler_create(YR_COMPILER** compiler);
 * }
 */
public static int yr_compiler_create(MemorySegment compiler) {
    var mh$ = yr_compiler_create$MH();
    try {
        return (int)mh$.invokeExact(compiler);
    } catch (Throwable ex$) {
        throw new AssertionError("should not reach here", ex$);
    }
}

/**
 * {@snippet :
 * void yr_compiler_destroy(YR_COMPILER* compiler);
 * }
 */
public static void yr_compiler_destroy(MemorySegment compiler) {
    var mh$ = yr_compiler_destroy$MH();
    try {
        mh$.invokeExact(compiler);
    } catch (Throwable ex$) {
        throw new AssertionError("should not reach here", ex$);
    }
}
```

All the generated bindings for the [yara.h header](https://github.com/VirusTotal/yara/blob/master/libyara/include/yara.h) file are available at
https://github.com/YARA-Java/YARA-Java/tree/master/yara-java

Going to the actual issue, I'm calling these methods from Java as follows:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.lang.foreign.Arena;
import java.lang.foreign.MemorySegment;

import static com.virustotal.yara.yara_h.ERROR_SUCCESS;
import static com.virustotal.yara.yara_h_1.*;

public class YaraTest {
    @Test
    public void testCompiler(){
        yr_initialize();

        try (Arena arena = Arena.openConfined()) {
            MemorySegment compiler = MemorySegment.allocateNative(YR_COMPILER.$LAYOUT(), arena.scope());

            int created = yr_compiler_create(compiler);
            Assertions.assertEquals(ERROR_SUCCESS(), created);

            yr_compiler_destroy(compiler);
        }

        yr_finalize();
    }
}
```

but it results in the following error, when calling the `yr_compiler_destroy` method:

```
double free or corruption (out)

Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)
```

I did also try to create a C_POINTER (represented by a generated layout class),

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.lang.foreign.Arena;
import java.lang.foreign.MemorySegment;

import static com.virustotal.yara.yara_h.ERROR_SUCCESS;
import static com.virustotal.yara.yara_h_1.*;

public class YaraTest {
    @Test
    public void testCompiler(){
        yr_initialize();

        try (Arena arena = Arena.openConfined()) {
            MemorySegment compiler = MemorySegment.allocateNative(YR_COMPILER.$LAYOUT(), arena.scope());
            MemorySegment compilerAddress = MemorySegment.allocateNative(Constants$root.C_POINTER$LAYOUT, arena.scope());
            compilerAddress.set(Constants$root.C_POINTER$LAYOUT, 0, MemorySegment.ofAddress(compiler.address()));

            int created = yr_compiler_create(compilerAddress);
            Assertions.assertEquals(ERROR_SUCCESS(), created);

            yr_compiler_destroy(compiler);
        }

        yr_finalize();
    }
}
```

but it results in a fatal error:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f9ae98dab44, pid=75962, tid=75963
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (20.0+29) (build 20-ea+29-2280)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (20-ea+29-2280, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libyara.so.8.0.0+0x3cb44]
#
# Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/usr/share/apport/apport -p%p -s%s -c%c -d%d -P%P -u%u -g%g -- %E" (or dumping to /mnt/bytes/Workspace/YARA-Java/yara-java/yara-java/core.75962)
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /mnt/bytes/Workspace/YARA-Java/yara-java/yara-java/hs_err_pid75962.log
[0,501s][warning][os] Loading hsdis library failed
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)
```

The full log is available here https://pastebin.com/a6xp6rLD.

What is the equivalent of `YR_COMPILER**` and `YR_COMPILER*` using Java Foreign API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code using the `&` operator in C can generally not be directly translated into Java. Instead you have to allocate the type passed to the `&` operator directly.

```
YR_COMPILER* compiler = NULL;
yr_compiler_create(&compiler);
```

Here the type of `compiler` is `YR_COMPILER*` so the layout is `C_POINTER`.

Your second attempt is really close, but you also have to read the pointer back from the `compilerAddress` segment. What your code does is this:

```
compiler -> YR_COMPILER (uninitialized)
compilerAddress -> C_POINTER (value is address of 'compiler')
```

Then the function call happens, which changes the value pointed to by `compilerAddress`, and you get:

```
compiler -> YR_COMPILER (uninitialized)
compilerAddress -> C_POINTER (value is address set by 'yr_compiler_create')
```

Since you then pass the uninitialized `compiler` pointer to `yr_compiler_destroy` it is not surprising the program crashes.

So, you just have to read back the pointer from `compilerAddress` *after* calling `yr_compiler_create`:

```
try (Arena arena = Arena.openConfined()) {
    MemorySegment compilerAddress = arena.allocate(C_POINTER); // YR_COMPILER**

    int created = yr_compiler_create(compilerAddress);
    Assertions.assertEquals(ERROR_SUCCESS(), created);

    MemorySegment compiler = compilerAddress.get(C_POINTER, 0); // YR_COMPILER*

    yr_compiler_destroy(compiler);
}
```

(Note that the `C_POINTER` layout should be generated in `yara_h.java`)

Essentially, the C code equivalent would be:

```
YR_COMPILER** compilerAddress = malloc(sizeof *compilerAddress);
yr_compiler_create(compilerAddress);
YR_COMPILER* compiler = *compilerAddress;
```

Which doesn't use `&`.

Comment: This manual "erasure" of all pointer types to `MemorySegment` takes a while to get used to. But from my experience, most FFI libraries have that problem.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Yes, and it doesn't help that structs are now also 'erased' to `MemorySegment`. We've been talking about having jextract generate more high-level types for pointers and structs, which I think would really help with figuring out the required level of indirection, but there are some performance pitfalls that we haven't figured out yet. (Though, I'm getting more and more convinced that it's worth doing either way)

Comment: Thank you Jorn for the clear explanation. Is there some updated official documentation and examples on how to properly use this new Foreign API?

Comment: I often find myself creating "thin" wrappers around `Addressable` (back in Java 16) - basically `record SomePtr (MemoryAddress address) implements Addressable {}`.

Comment: @1Z10 Check out https://github.com/openjdk/panama-foreign/blob/foreign-memaccess%2Babi/doc/panama_memaccess.md and https://github.com/openjdk/panama-foreign/blob/foreign-memaccess%2Babi/doc/panama_ffi.md There's also the jextract samples in the jextract repo